# In what directory do i put my mysql config.php files when setting up a website/app?

Tags: php, directory, config

Hi I'm new to putting up websites.  I have a document root: home/user/public_html/www.example.com/public where all of my static file should go to be publiclly viewable.  But many of these files include config.php.  These config.php files have user names and passwords so it just doesn't seem right to put them in the public folder.

1. Where should these files go?
2. If I move the configs to a different directory (I have tried) then the static files can't find the config files anymore.  Would I point to the new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup you need change the location of config.php with respect to the static files. If I understood correctly, by default they both are in same directory, so you must have
     `include 'config.php';` 
if you want to move them into a new folder, suppose name of the folder is hidden, then you have to change it to :
    `include 'hidden/config.php';`

Finally if you decided to move up one directory, you have to use
     `include '../config.php';`

You can read in detail about relative paths here:
[Absolute vs relative links](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)

Comment: thanks for the answer! another question. if i have a login.php file, should that be in the public folder or say one folder up?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I was out of town for few days. As PorridgeBear answered login.php should be public folder, reason being that if I need to login to your site, I need access to that page. All the files in a folder above public_html are not accessible to outside world.

Answer (score 1):

Well, WordPress, one of the more popular and largest platforms out there just puts a wp-config.php file into the document root, so if it's good enough for them you could say it's good enough for you :)

You can of course store the config.php file 1 level up from your actual document root. PHP can still access it if given the correct path.

E.g. http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-config.php

Each file that includes config.php needs to reference it with the correct path. If you just store the config.php in the root you can change all the includes to use

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');
```

This will work no matter the location of the including file.

Comment: thanks for the tip!  another question.  if i have a login.php file, should that be in the public folder or say one folder up?

Comment: You can keep logic scripts inside your web folder, settings are the only things people generally move up out of the web root.